# Jquery hide or show span by id

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to hide and show 2 different  elements when clicking on a button. Its not working.

when I click the Delete button, the  hides but the confirmDeleteSpan is not showing.

Please help.

Here is the HTML

```
 <div class="card-footer">
            <form asp-action="DeleteUser" asp-route-id="@user.Id" method="post">
                <a asp-action="EditUser" asp-controller="Administration"
                   asp-route-id="@user.Id" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Edit</a>

            <span id="confirmDeleteSpan_@user.Id" style="display:none" >
                <span> Are you sure you want to delete</span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"
                   onclick="confirmDelete('@user.Id', false)">No</a>
            </span>

            <span id="deleteSpan_@user.Id">
                <a href="#/" class="btn btn-danger"
                   onclick="confirmDelete('@user.Id', true)">Delete</a>
            </span>    

            </form>
        </div>
```

Here is the JQUERY script:

```
   function confirmDelete(uniqueId, isTrue) {

    var deleteSpan = 'deleteSpan_' + uniqueId;
    var confirmDeleteSpan = 'confirmDeletespan_' + uniqueId;

    if (isTrue) {
        $('#' + deleteSpan).hide("slow");
        $('#' + confirmDeleteSpan).show();         
    } else {
        $('#' + deleteSpan).show("slow");
        $('#' + confirmDeleteSpan).hide();

    }
}
```

Here is View Source

```
<div class="card-footer">
            <form method="post" action="/Administration/DeleteUser/ccebd1b9-1a85-46e4-b4a1-5e73e9734ba7">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="/Administration/EditUser/ccebd1b9-1a85-46e4-b4a1-5e73e9734ba7">Edit</a>

            <span id="confirmDeleteSpan_ccebd1b9-1a85-46e4-b4a1-5e73e9734ba7" style="display:none">
                <span> Are you sure you want to delete</span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"
                   onclick="confirmDelete('ccebd1b9-1a85-46e4-b4a1-5e73e9734ba7', false)">No</a>
            </span>

            <span id="deleteSpan_ccebd1b9-1a85-46e4-b4a1-5e73e9734ba7">
                <a href="#/" class="btn btn-danger"
                   onclick="confirmDelete('ccebd1b9-1a85-46e4-b4a1-5e73e9734ba7', true)">Delete</a>
            </span>    

            <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8CFNAH60_plMlRrZQdMVKfL3M75wB5l7cYhvyqKtgU0iMsX0rPzU0T6yG1eRaGRT2jqbJUpi6vcM1r-nDfFymtVtqi1P2fUvBEhzU5-EgvZ9Mi4_SiLjse4-0LBpPTSrEHeXtjKdPvUvEcYyNtw7Xe1nTTX0tVmoSpaYkKqFjT_SdsAxEQjbxAfVU1nqJBho8w" /></form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you confirm once and check what is the value of `<span id="confirmDeleteSpan_@user.Id"` showing in the UI in browser inspect mode. Also, put some `debugger` or console.log inside `confirmDelete` function and post the values you get for `uniqueId`. Also, are there multiple `card-footer` divs in your code or just one?

Comment: The @user.Id value pulls through

Comment: Here is the View Source Code, yes, there are card-footers per @user.Id